# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean definition

Tags: java, spring

Trying to run a simple spring based program. I'm using spring-framework-3.0.5.
Not sure what is causing this error!!

spring.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="user" name="com.spsam.UserPOJO">
        <property name="id" value="1351231"/>
        <property name="name" value="Ninam"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Sample class:

```
public class Sample1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        UserPOJO user = (UserPOJO) context.getBean("user");
        user.getUserDetails();
    }
}
```

Exception got :

```
Dec 12, 2013 6:59:08 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@744607b5: startup date [Thu Dec 12 18:59:08 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 12, 2013 6:59:08 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
Dec 12, 2013 6:59:08 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6e58f809: defining beans [user]; root of factory hierarchy
Dec 12, 2013 6:59:08 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6e58f809: defining beans [user]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'user' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean definition
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.spsam.Sample1.main(Sample1.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean definition
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:52)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
    ... 13 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Change name to class. Error message is pretty clear

Comment: In the xml file, you have the attribute 'name'. But Spring is complaining that it can't find the correct bean class. You'd also need the 'class' name to be provided in the xml.

Comment: Error also comes when using ResourceBundleViewResolver in your view.properties for no good reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-definition) explains

> A bean definition essentially is a recipe for creating one or more
>   objects. The container looks at the recipe for a named bean when
>   asked, and uses the configuration metadata encapsulated by that bean
>   definition to create (or acquire) an actual object.
>
> If you use XML-based configuration metadata, you specify the type (or
>   class) of object that is to be instantiated in the class attribute of
>   the  element. **This class attribute, which internally is a
>   Class property on a BeanDefinition instance, is usually mandatory**.

Your bean definition is missing the `class` attribute. Add it

```
<bean id="user" name="com.spsam.UserPOJO" class="com.spsam.UserPOJO">
    <property name="id" value="1351231"/>
    <property name="name" value="Ninam"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring MVC ResourceBundleViewResolver, and your view beans are not written right in view.properties you will get this error.

See this link to help verify your view beans are correct.
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-resourcebundleviewresolver-example/